# How to simplify ¬p ^ q?

Tags: logic

I'm starting to learn about laws, and I'm getting a little lost sometimes. My teacher just showed and example where he simplified  **~p ^ q**  to  **~p**. I've checked every law and have no idea how did he get there, the only one I could think was Morgans, but I only get **p v ~q**. Can you help me understand? Thank you so much.

Comment: There's got to be more to it than that: obviously neither $\neg p\wedge q$ nor $\neg(p\wedge q)$ (usually "$\neg p\wedge q$" is interpreted as "$(\neg p)\wedge q$") is equivalent to $\neg p$. What *is* true is that $\neg p\wedge q$ implies $\neg p$, since $a\wedge b$ implies $a$. Maybe that's what he actually said?

Comment: They are obviously *not* the same.  But, there is an *inference* rule called Simplification that can be used to *infer*  $\neg p$ from $\neg p \land q$ .. maybe your professor used that?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Does doing too much logic brainwash us? We even used the same words, for crying out loud!

Comment: @NoahSchweber I swear that's it ehehehe, but I think someone gave a plausible answer below. Thank you all for such quick responses!

Comment: @Bram28 I believe so!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule of inference that says we can conclude $A$, given $A\wedge B$, is called "simplification". This is potentially confusing, because in algebra, we often use the word "simplification" to refer to moves that are equivalences ($\Leftrightarrow$), whereas this rule only goes one way ($(A\wedge B)\implies A$).

In this case, our statement $A$ is $\neg p$, and we can obtain it by applying the "simplification" rule to $(\neg p) \wedge q$.

Comment: Thank you. I've checked some slides in future classes, and I've seen this "law of simplification" for the first time. I do believe you are right. I guess our teacher didn't think this would be useful if shown before this example. Thank you so much!